# Palindrome Number In Java

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Input
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Input a number: ");
        int num = sc.nextInt();

        //Solve
        for (int i = num+1; i>num; i++)
        {
            int numCheck = 0;
            int r;
            int numAfter = i;
            while (true)
            {
                r = i%10;
                numCheck = numCheck*10+r;
                numAfter = (numAfter-r)/10;
                i = numAfter;
                if (numAfter==0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (numCheck==num)
            {
                System.out.println("Minumum palindrome number that greater than input number: "+i);
                break;
            }
        }



}
```

I am writing a program to print a minimum palindrome number (ex: 101, 232, 353, 303, 424,...) and greater than an input number (input by java.util.Scanner). 
But this program didn't print anything.

Could you help me to fix it?

Comment: If I were in your shoes, the first thing I'd do would be to step into the code using a debugger. What happens when you try this?

Comment: please try to debug your code, step through it line by line to see where you are getting into an infinite loop or breaks out of the loop entirely because the loop condition is no linger met.

Comment: It probably didn't print anything because it never finished execution. If you were to enter `2`, it would start off from `3` and kept incrementing until forever because once it reached the `Integer.MAX_VALUE` it would overflow and start again from `Integer.MIN_VALUE` which would break the `for()`-loop's condition so it'd just exit without printing anything. Or something worse than that.

Comment: Hint: `i = numAfter;` looks suspicious, assigning *some* value to your loop-variable is dangerous if you are not very careful and know what you are doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `numCheck` should end up being equal to the original value of the current `i` in order for that `i` to be a palindrome.

However, your stop condition is `if (numCheck==num)`, which will never be true.

It should be `if (numCheck==i)`, but that will also fail, since you don't keep the original value of `i`.

The following works:

```
    for (int i = num+1; i>num; i++)
    {
        int numCheck = 0;
        int r;
        int numAfter = i;
        while (true)
        {
            r = numAfter%10;
            numCheck = numCheck*10+r;
            numAfter = (numAfter-r)/10;
            if (numAfter==0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (numCheck==i)
        {
            System.out.println("Minumum palindrome number that greater than input number: "+i);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Now `i` is never modified within the inner loop (`i = numAfter;` was removed), so you can compare its value to `numCheck` after the inner loop is done.

BTW, the code can be more readable this way:

```
    int i = num + 1;
    while (true)
    {
        int numCheck = 0;
        int r;
        int numAfter = i;
        while (numAfter != 0)
        {
            r = numAfter%10;
            numCheck = numCheck*10+r;
            numAfter = (numAfter-r)/10;
        }
        if (numCheck==i)
        {
            System.out.println("Minumum palindrome number that greater than input number: "+i);
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
```